# Javascript, Get unique values or group by value.id from an each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, regex, foreach, underscore.js

I have values stored in localStorage and convert them into arrays after retrieving them from localStorage.

I only want to return unique values or probably group them so there are no duplicates. I used _underscore for the loop.

```
$.get_played_songs = function(){
                if (localStorage.getItem("local_songs") === null) { 
                    recent_holder.html('Play some music');
                    } else {
                    var StoredPlays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('local_songs'));  
                    var i=0
                    _.each(StoredPlays, function(value, key){
                        recent_holder.append("<div class='recently_played_jams' data-recently_played_sid='"+value.sid+"'>"+value.title+"</div>");
                    });
                } 
            }
```

console logging "value" returns this.

```
Object { title: "Song1", sid: "47" }
Object { title: "Song1", sid: "47" } 
Object { title: "Song1", sid: "47" }
Object { title: "Song12", sid: "47" }
Object { title: "Song2", sid: "47" }
Object { title: "Song2", sid: "47" }
Object { title: "Song2", sid: "47" }
```

So I want to group by sid. Maybe some regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? And where are you stuck? Underscore has *lots* of utilities for operating on arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder,  Ok group is a bit out, something like in sql where one can "GROUP BY USER_ID", with all these, Im trying to explain that I don't want to return duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) lets you pass in a function that determines what to look at when determining uniqueness, so if it's `sid` that makes them unique:

```
StoredPlays = _.uniq(StoredPlays, function(play) { return play.sid; });
```

```js
var StoredPlays = [
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" } ,
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song12", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" }
];
StoredPlays = _.uniq(StoredPlays, function(play) { return play.sid; });
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(StoredPlays));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or if it's `sid` **and** `title`:

```
StoredPlays = _.uniq(StoredPlays, function(play) { return play.sid + "/" + play.title; });
```

```js
var StoredPlays = [
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" } ,
  { title: "Song1", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song12", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" },
  { title: "Song2", sid: "47" }
];
StoredPlays = _.uniq(StoredPlays, function(play) { return play.sid + "/" + play.title; });
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(StoredPlays));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of underscore.js you can use Lo-Das.js ( https://lodash.com/docs#uniq ) which is in general much faster and 100% compatibe with your current code

Comment: @Konstantin: But does it use the incorrect term "iteratee" for *iterator* functions like Underscore does? ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, what is 'play', that you put as the argument?

Comment: Shouldn't it be _.uniq(StoredPlays, function(value, key){
                       console.log(value);
                    });

Comment: @Relm: `play` is each entry in `StoredPlays`. I've added live examples. I do recommend reading through the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thnkas. Accepted the answer.